# Print Loop Number in ongoing script in terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am running a long python program in terminal and I have paused it. Is there a way to read out the value of an array in the script, or print out the loop number of the script without needing to restart the terminal program?

Comment: Paste some code?

Comment: I can't edit my program because it's already running. I was wondering if there was a way to use terminal to print out some sort of debug statement, without interacting with the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you count the loop numbers

```py
loop_count = 0
for x in range(10):
    # do some work
    loop_count += 1
    print("Loop Count:", loop_count)
```

And to print out a list or array

```py
from pprint import pprint

some_array = [1, 2, "text", [1, 3], True]
pprint(some_array)
```

Note: examples here are in Python because question is tagged as Python.

**Edit**

You can not edit a already running program in any way because python compiles the code to python bytecode (*`__pycache__`*) internally when you want to change the code, python will have to recompile it causing it to start all over again

Comment: The problem is that I can't edit the program, because that would involve restarting it, and I don't want to do that. I was wondering if there was some sort of way to do that in terminal without touching the python program.